# Get next table cell vertically in table with rowspans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find index of cell in table below a given cell. Imagine that I don't know anything about td_end, I just click at td_start and need to find td_end. Example (need find index of red cell(td_end), knowing index of green cell (td_start)): http://jsfiddle.net/r5BDW/65/

Problem that table will contain a lot of cells with `rowspan` attr, so usual searching by equal index will not work. Any advice how to find such cells?

example table:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr><td>111</td><td rowspan="3">22</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td class="td_start">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td class="td_end">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>22</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td >22</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

console.log($('.td_start').index() ) // =1
console.log($('.td_end').index() )  // =2
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code within your question. IF jsFiddle goes down, as it frequently does, your question would be unanswerable.

Comment: Any expected value. Just need to find right cell (or its index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that would be almost a crazy act to guess all the possible colspan and rowspan combinations.

What I would try with, is to literally
 ***"touch"* the element that is visually beneath the *selector* element** using `elementFromPoint`

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/y4uLLyw0/2/)**

```
$.fn.nextVert = function(){
  var b = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var nxtV = document.elementFromPoint(b.left, b.bottom+10);
  if(nxtV.tagName==="TD") return $(nxtV);
};


$('.td_start').nextVert().text("hello");
console.log( $('.td_start').nextVert().index() ); // 2
```

by simply getting the `elementFromPoint`
 starting from the *this* bottom value + some tiny offset (I used 10px)

Comment: maybe I will use it,  tnx

Comment: @user1931780 the above is just an idea, you can improve the code by letting it handle things like `.nextVert("td")` etc...

Answer (score 1):

chek this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/r5BDW/68/

find td with same left position

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $td2=$('.td_start2');
    fidnBelow($td2);

    var $td=$('.td_start');
    fidnBelow($td);
});

function fidnBelow($td)
{
    var rez='';

    var p=$td.position();
    var left=p.left;

    var td_count=$('tr').size();
    var ind_tr=$td.parent().index();
    var $table=$('#table');
    ind_tr++;


    for(i=ind_tr;i<td_count;i++)
    {
        var $below_tr=$table.find('tr').eq(i)

        $below_tr.find('td').each(function(){
            var tp=$(this).position();
            var tleft=tp.left;

            if(left==tp.left) rez=$(this).html();                    
        })

        if(rez!='') break;
    }

    alert(rez);
}
```